# Python: profiling blocks of code

Tags: python, profiling

I have a Python function in which I want to find most slowing-down places. Just not I'm using `cProfile`, but I have an additional functionality.

I don't want to split my function into a dozen of sub-functions: it looks a bit bulky and annoying.

Isn't there instead a way to profile a function line-by-line? Or add something like `timer_start(timer_id)` and `timer_stop(timer_id)` before and after each block of code I want to profile execution time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using IPython already, you should give it a look. It has magic functions like `%lprun` which make line-by-line profiling easy. Take a look at [Timing and Profiling in IPython](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html)